# How to get the specific branch name at an index from 'git branch --list'

Tags: git, git-bash

When we do `git branch --list`, it shows the list of branch name such as:

```
  master
  develop
  features/do-A
  features/do-B
  features/do-C
```

Is there any ways to get the branch name at a specific position from the list?

For example:

```
>> git branch --list --at-position 2
>> features/do-A
```

```
>> git branch --list --at-position 4
>> features/do-C
```

The reason why i need: with the command, i can do `pbcopy` instead of copy it using mouse or type it manually?

Comment: For scripting, use `git for-each-ref` (or more generally, avoid Git "porcelain" commands in favor of "plumbing" commands, as the latter are designed for scripts). To extract line `$n`: `whatever | sed -n ${n}p`. Hence `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | sed -n 3p` to print the third branch. The default `--sort` is alphabetical by refname.

Comment: @torek, super cool. This is exactly what i need. Thank you, Tokek

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a shell solution works for you?

```bash
$ git branch --list | head -3 | tail -1
features/do-A

$ git branch --list | head -5 | tail -1
features/do-C
```

**NOTE:** relying on a list position will depend on the list being always sorted in the same way. Probably you should look into the `--sort` option of `git branch`.

Answer (score 0):

As @torek mentioned in the comment in the question,

`git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | sed -n 3p` is exactly what i. need